# How can I test a native react module locally on a local app before publishing it

Tags: react-native

I created a mini react native library following [this article](https://medium.com/wix-engineering/creating-a-native-module-in-react-native-93bab0123e46). Before I publish the article I want to test it on a local app I created and I haven't seen an article that explains how to do this online. Please I need suggestions

Comment: https://medium.com/@the1mills/how-to-test-your-npm-module-without-publishing-it-every-5-minutes-1c4cb4b369be
This article explains what you need to achieve very nicely.

Comment: @romin21 would this work for react native